# How can i require a field if another has been filled?

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

i'm trying to require multiple fields only if one of these have been filled, otherwise they are optional. But i can't figure out how to get the values of the fields and ask it if they are blank.

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'gw_conditional_requirement' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation', 'gw_conditional_requirement' );
function gw_conditional_requirement( $form ) {
    $var = False;
    foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){
        
        if( ( ( $field['id'] >= 78 && $field['id'] <= 100 ) || $field['id'] == 253)){
            if(rgpost($field->adminLabel) != ''){
                $var = True;
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($form['fields'] as &$field){
        
        if( ( ( $field['id'] >= 78 && $field['id'] <= 100 ) || $field['id'] == 253)){
            if($var == True){
                $field['isRequired'] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $form;
}
```

In this code i go through all these fields to see if any has been filled an then i do it again requiring them if so.
Is there a way to get if this fields have been filled?

Comment: I haven't tested your code but in theory, it should work, the only thing that I don't understand is this check
`if(rgpost($field->adminLabel) != '')` shouldn't you be checking the field value instead of the admin label?

Comment: @Sherif That's just the part that i can't figure out, how can i get the value of the field?